# How to get the "resource name" while using the AWS CloudTrail processing library

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudtrail

I am using the [AWS CloudTrail processing library](https://github.com/aws/aws-cloudtrail-processing-library) to pull Cloudtrail logs from AWS. In the screenshot image of event history below (taken from the CloudTrail web console), the name of the bucket affected by a change is reflected under the column: `Resource name` . How can I retrieve this same value using the `aws-cloudtrail-processing-library`. The library returns the name of the bucket where CloudTrail saves the log files and not the affected bucket (highlighted). Also, even after downloading the logs from the bucket, I do not see this information.

[image]

Here is the snippet of my processing class:

```
public class AuditorCloudTrail {


public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(AuditorCloudTrail.class);



    final AWSCloudTrailProcessingExecutor executor = new AWSCloudTrailProcessingExecutor.Builder(
            new AuditorEventsProcessor(), new AuditorCloudTrailConfig()).withSourceFilter(new AuditorSourceFilter())
                    .withProgressReporter(new AuditorProgressReporter()).withEventFilter(new AuditorEventsFilter())
                    .withExceptionHandler(new AuditorExceptionHandler()).build();
    executor.start();

    // add shut down hook to gracefully stop executor (optional)
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            logger.info("Shut Down Hook is called.");
            executor.stop();
        }
    });

    // register a Default Uncaught Exception Handler (optional)
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {

            // Two options here:
            // First, we can call System.exit(1); in such case shut down hook will be
            // called.
            // Second, we can optionally restart another executor and start.
            final AWSCloudTrailProcessingExecutor executor = new AWSCloudTrailProcessingExecutor.Builder(
                    new AuditorEventsProcessor(), new AuditorCloudTrailConfig()).withSourceFilter(new AuditorSourceFilter())
                            .withEventFilter(new AuditorEventsFilter())
                            .withProgressReporter(new AuditorProgressReporter())
                            .withExceptionHandler(new AuditorExceptionHandler()).build();
            executor.start();

        }
    });

    // can optionally limit running time, or remove both lines so it is running
    // forever. (optional)
    Thread.sleep(24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    executor.stop();
}
```

**and the method that filters events:**

```
   public boolean filterEvent(CloudTrailEvent event) throws CallbackException {
    CloudTrailEventData eventData = event.getEventData();    

    String eventSource = eventData.getEventSource();    

    try {
        saveEvent(eventData);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return (eventSource.equals(IAM_EVENTS) || 
   eventSource.equals(S3_EVENTS));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened this question as an [issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-cloudtrail-processing-library/issues/10) on the `AWS Cloudtrail processing engine`'s GitHub [repository](https://github.com/aws/aws-cloudtrail-processing-library). The answer I received was that this feature is not supported at the moment using the processing engine. Therefore, the workaround was to use `Logstash`(requires cloudtrail [plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.3/plugins-codecs-cloudtrail.html) installation) to pull the `cloudtrail` logs into a `mongodb`server from a pre-configured AWS s3 bucket as described [here](https://www.blog.labouardy.com/cloudtrail-elk/), from where normal processing can be used to extract the desired events including the `resources` involved.